# Use numbers, instead of seconds on annotated time line

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, annotatedtimeline

I am trying to use google charts, ['Annotated Time Line'](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline).

On the column I want to use numbers, which

```
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Start' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'End' });
```

But the problem is, still the number is taken as milli second, hence after each 60 seconds, clock is set back to 0 (1 minute) and then it continues. I want it to show as 60, 65, 70 and so on instead of 0, 5, 10 (after each minute).

```
Current
```

[image: Current]

```
Display as
```

[image: Display as]

Is there a quick way to do this?

> EDIT: Link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6M2sH/227/) (with original data) 
>   with simplified data: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6M2sH/228/)

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle or codepen with your data example?

Comment: @juvian added link to jsfiddle with original data and simplified data.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't set ticks option as with other charts. If you really need to, can make some dom manipulation to the axis text. Is your data static or dynamic?

Comment: @juvian It's dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am guessing that the axes always have constant increment, but guess its always like that:

```
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'ready',function(){
                var axes=[];
                $('#time-line svg text').each(function(){
                    var t = $(this).text();
                    if(t == parseInt(t).toString() && t.length > 0){ // if its a number text, its an axis
                        axes.push($(this))
                    }
                })
                var inc = Number(axes[1].text()); // increment
                var sum=0;
                for(var i=0;i<axes.length;i++){
                    var txt=axes[i].text();
                    var num=Number(txt);
                    axes[i].text(sum); // set new value
                    sum+=inc;
                }

            })




            chart.draw(dataTable);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6M2sH/233/

Comment: Thanks Juvian, actually I was looking for some option with chart itself. But yes your idea would work as well, also the increment might not be same but yes, this does help me, I can further modify your answer to fulfil my criteria. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great that it was useful. Good luck with your proyect